# Specify the name of storage account from Azure Function that uses type CloudQueue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function which takes a message from IoTHub and places it on a given queue for processing. The queue is determined dynamically at runtime by the incoming message data and placed on the queue with a short ExpirationTime as I only want messages to persist for a couple of seconds:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public static void Run(MyType myEventHubMessage, IBinder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
    int TTL = 3;
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEventHubMessage);
    var msg = new CloudQueueMessage(data);

    string outputQueueName = myEventHubMessage.DeviceId;
    QueueAttribute queueAttribute = new QueueAttribute(outputQueueName);
    CloudQueue outputQueue = binder.Bind<CloudQueue>(queueAttribute);

    outputQueue.AddMessage(msg, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TTL), null, null, null);

}

public class MyType
{
  public string DeviceId { get; set; }
  public double Field1 { get; set; }
  public double Field2 { get; set; }
  public double Field3 { get; set; }

}
```

This, is working well and messages are being written to my queue. However, the queue its being written to is NOT the storage account I want to use! It seems to be picking up a storage account from somewhere else?!?

I have a connection property in my `function.json`:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "myEventHubMessage",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "someiothub",
      "connection": "IoTHubConnectionString"
    },
    {
      "type": "CloudQueue",
      "name": "$return",
      "queueName": "{DeviceId}",
      "connection": "NAME_OF_CON_STRING_I_WANT_TO_USE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

but its being totally ignored. In face, I can remove the value or key/value pair altogether from the JSON and the function still runs and writes to what appears to be a default storage account somewehere.

I've tried adding the `[StorageAccount("NAME_OF_CON_STR_I_WANT_TO_USE")]` attribute to my Run function, but that also seems to be ignored and I also tried creating an Attribute array and passing both QueueAttribute and `StorageAccountAttribute` to `binder.Bind<T>(attributeArray)` but that complains that it cannot accept an array.

Does anyone know first where its getting the storage account from that it is using and more importantly how I can set the storage account name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track: you need to pass `StorageAccountAttribute` in an array of attributes to the binder. To a reason which is unknown to me, it looks like only async version of concrete class `Binder` method supports passing an array. Something like that should work:

```
public static async Task Run(MyType myEventHubMessage, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
    // ...
    var queueAttribute = new QueueAttribute(outputQueueName);
    var storageAttribute = new StorageAccountAttribute("MyAccount");
    var attributes = new Attribute[] { queueAttribute, storageAttribute };
    CloudQueue outputQueue = await binder.BindAsync<CloudQueue>(attributes);
    // ...
}
```

By the way, you don't need to specify any configuration in `function.json` for imperative bindings: they will be ignored. Just delete those to avoid confusion (keep the trigger, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is this documented anywhere? I'm getting the same error passing in an array: 2017-06-13T09:43:56.381 (20,65): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Attribute[]' to 'System.Attribute'

Comment: I can't find the documentation... Are you sure you use `Binder` (not `IBinder`) and `BindAsync` (not `Bind`)? Works for me.

Comment: Sorry, you were correct. Forgot to change IBinder to Binder. Works like a charm now. Thanks again for the help :)